# How to color a sentence?

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown, formatting

[Question edited on 5/28/16] I have read this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user). But I still don't understand how to color <s>the text</s> a sentence. Can one actually do that?

- Could anyone give an example for coloring <s>the text?</s> a sentence?
- Where should I go when I have the similar formatting question?

Comment: Use \color{blue}{text} to get $\color{blue}{text}$

Comment: Here is a list of predefined colors which can be used: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Predefined_colors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\color{blue}{\textrm{One can color text}}$ by writing

`$\color{blue}{\textrm{One can color text}}$`

Comment: This is a poor way to do it. If you now already felt the need to bump this old thread for adding this answer you could at least include a solution that does not use a font different from the one used for actual text.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the discussion under the answer of Mariano. And neither your comment. What do you mean by "a font different from the one used for actual *text*"?

Comment: It is not the same font. What is unclear about this. Look closely and you will see it is not the same. And on the "text": you included a math environment, this is not text anymore.

Comment: Ah, so the point is that the answer depends on how I phrase my question. If one wants to color some *words*, then he/she can use the math environment. But no way to color *text*. I have never understood this until today. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: Yes. Coloring text is not supported. However, using MathJax it is possible to introduce color "through the backdoor." There are however several disadvantages to using it in this way, it is therefore discouraged to do what you recommend in your answer.  A slightly better way is explained in  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20503/ But one still should not used it to insert color all over.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot color text. That can be deduced from the post you linked to.

Comment: $\rm \color{red}{BUT}\color{green}{\ YOU}\color{blue}{\ CAN!} $

Comment: @Bill: I made the same point a few hours ago. But in order not to encourage it I removed my comment. (I agree that Mariano's answer invites such a comment but I'd be surprised if he hadn't known about that trick)

Comment: I even object to `\rm`, in fact :) A mismatch set of fonts is never nice on the eye... let alone if they are randomly colored!

Comment: @Bill: Mariano explicitly stated "text". You did not color "text". `:)`

Comment: @Willie But it is TeXt! For the rare occasions one needs such, this kludge usually suffices.

Comment: @Mar RGB is not random. Nor is anyone recommending fruit salad text or "mismatched" fonts.

Comment: @Bill: Did you do that in the $$ environment?

Comment: @Jack Yes, I used the LaTeX \color command.

Comment: $\rm\color{pink} {\pi} $

Comment: That link doesn't mention color at all. How did you conclude it's deducible from the link that texts can't be colored?!